# Can you find Redrum's Pirate Treasure?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Redrum is a **Dutch** pirate and when he set foot on an unhabited island he lost his treasure. Or as the Dutch call it his "**Schat**". Can you figure out what his treasure/"schat" is?

[image: Pirate Redrum's Treasure]

Hint 1:

> There's a simply logic way to solve this

Hint 2:

> Of course, pirate Redrum was not born with a pirate name. His parents Jacob & Sofia named their son Onno. After he set sail as a rookie Pirate, he poisoned Captain Greybeards' wine and killed him. Since then his fellow pirates called him Redrum.

Hint 3:

> Some people might overthink this puzzle while they should focus on Onno.

Hint 4:

> This puzzle type has so many different names...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redrum's "Pirate Treasure" is:

> his precious **PARROT**!

Because this puzzle is a disguised...

> **nonogram** grid-deduction puzzle. To work this out, count up all the numbers of one colour in each of the two grids - in all cases, the numbers match (i.e. there are 13 reds, 2 oranges, 6 yellows, etc. in each). Moreover, there are 11 grey 'X's in each, and the highest sum for all numbers between two X's is 12 (see the bottom row of the lower grid). This suggests that it might be possible to arrange the grids to form a 12x12 nonogram using the 11 grey 'X's as dividers between row/column clue sets.
>
>  Let's do so like this:
>
>  [image: Unsolved nonogram, no longer disguised]
>
>  Here, I have used the top grid for the down clues and the bottom grid for the across clues, reading across the grid rows and using the X's as dividers, as suggested.

Is this uniquely solvable? Yes, it is! And if we do so using standard rules for this puzzle type (starting with the maxed-out 10th row and following the straightforward logic from there), we end up with the following solution:

> [image: Solved nonogram, revealing a colourful parrot]
>
>  Redrum's pretty polly, sat upon a leafy branch in a tree! Note further that 'Schat' in Dutch, after all, means 'darling', something one might call one's pet rather than an inanimate treasure chest.

Comment: OH! I would have never guessed that. How'd you figure it out? I've been working on this for so long lol.

Comment: ONNO! nONNOgram.

Comment: But, simply logic?

Comment: OMG! I've been reading hint 3 like this the whole time: Some people might overthink this puzzle when they focus on Onno. So, I've been not focusing on Onno!

Comment: @LoganSweeney Re how I figured it out, see the second spoiler in my write-up... I noticed a few facts about the numbers and colours, and the number of 'X's. and was able to deduce the puzzle type from that. Then I tried to rearrange the grids as per my first image and then just worked my way through it to see if it was solvable in that state - and it was! :)

Comment: The 'simply logic' mention is a reference to how to solve the hidden puzzle. No guesswork is required when working your way through its solution, it has a completely logical path (like [tag:grid-deduction] puzzles should)- try and solve it for yourself, starting with my blank grid; it would make for a nice break-time puzzle :)

Comment: Woah!  mind is blown! How did you even see that? I mean I know it is a common trick to convert data into nonograms in puzzles but to see this connection is ridiculous and not to mention find a way to make a valid one from information which  doesn’t resemble the grid in the slightest is well simply unreal! This is the craziest solution a have seen in the last 3 or so months. If there was a poll on best answer for meta I would nominate this.

Comment: @PDT I first noticed the two orange '1's in each grid, then that all blues and all yellows each added to 6 in each. Repeating this for all colours there was a 1-1 correspondence between the two grids. So that set me to thinking that these were probably the two complementary components of *this type of puzzle*, but wasn't sure how to assemble it. It was only this morning though that I realised that there were also equal numbers of grey X's, and that was when I realised these might be useful for dividing them up. First attempt at construction looked solvable... so I saw it through to the end :)

Comment: (And thanks! It was a satisfying solve once I got over the barriers to identifying it...)

Comment: Well, great job!

Comment: I have two questions. How do you add hints that you click to reveal. Second, I just finished making a puzzle, but, it's not letting me submit it. It's not even saying anything, but, the review your question button isn't working.

Comment: @LoganSweeney 1. Click-and-reveal hints are known as spoiler blocks - type '>!' at the start of a line to make it a spoiler. 2. I would advise against adding hints at initial posting - let people see your puzzle without hints first, then add after 24 hours if you wish. 3. Re your issue with posting: Copy your puzzle text first so you don't lose it, then try hard-refreshing your browser (Ctrl+F5) or using a different browser to see if that happens elsewhere. (NB Usually better to ask general questions like these in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)...)

Comment: - Treasure means "Schat" in Dutch. And "Schat"  in Dutch also means "Darling". Redrum's Darling is, indeed, his PARROT!
- ONNO refers to NONOgram
- A NONOGRAM is a SIMPLY LOGIC puzzle.
- Other names for nonogram; anjie puzzle, Paint by Numbers,Crosspix, Griddlers,Pic-a-Pix, Picross, Picma, PrismaPixels, Pixel Puzzles, Crucipixel, Edel, FigurePic, Hanjie, HeroGlyphix, Illust-Logic, Japanese Crosswords, etc.

CONGRATULATIONS TO @Stiv

Comment: Only 8 upvotes? This deserves at least 20…

Comment: Thanks for the extra bounty @PDT :)